# How to flush table (PyTables) when the I/O buffer reaches a certain size

Tags: python, pytables

I've started using PyTables to log large amounts of data, and I'd like to control `flush()` calls by keeping track of the I/O buffer of the file and only flushing when a user-define cap is hit. Is there a way to query how much memory is taken up in the buffer?

Comment: It would be easier for you to keep track of other things like number of items in the table and control the flushing from there.